# Is there a way to add a splash screen while lightdm is switching users

Tags: 14.04, lightdm

I share a laptop with my 10 year old daughter. We're using Ubuntu 14.04lts and when she switches to her own account LightDM blanks the screen for a 10 to 20 seconds, sometimes longer.

For a 10 year old this is quite frustrating as she thinks the systems frozen and then proceeds to do press & hold the power switch.

Is it possible to display an image rather than a black/blank screen